# What's the difference between DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber) & PhoneAttribute

Tags: c#, .net, data-annotations, validationattribute

What's the difference between using [`DataType` Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataTypeAttribute) and passing in a value of [`DataType.Phone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType) and the [`Phone` Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.PhoneAttribute) which inherits from `DataType` and automatically sets `DataType.Phone`?

Is there any difference between these two classes?

```cs
class Person {
   [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
   public string PhoneNumber {get;set;}
}
```

```cs
class Person {
   [Phone]
   public string PhoneNumber {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### *TLDR*: `[Phone]` provides validation logic while `[DataType]` does not

The inheritance chain looks like this:

`Attribute`
  ↳ `ValidationAttribute`
       ↳ `DataTypeAttribute`
            ↳ `PhoneAttribute`

So both are instances of `ValidationAttribute`, however both don't provide Validation out of the box.  The DataType base class just provides the structure for assigning an `enum DataType` and leaves overriding the validation up to the caller

#### `DataType` - According to the Docs:

> When you apply the `DataTypeAttribute` attribute to a data field you must do the following:
>
> - Issue validation errors as appropriate.

#### `DataType` - According to the Source Code:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DataTypeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    /// <summary> Override of <see cref="ValidationAttribute.IsValid(object)" /> </summary>
    /// <remarks>This override always returns <c>true</c>.  Subclasses should override this to provide the correct result.</remarks>
    /// <param name="value">The value to validate</param>
    /// <returns>Unconditionally returns <c>true</c></returns>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"> is thrown if the current attribute is ill-formed.</exception>
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        EnsureValidDataType();

        return true;
    }
 }
```

**Aside**: Since you are required to override `IsValid`, I'm not sure why .NET didn't mark the class and property as [`abstract`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract) to guarantee an implementation programmatically.

#### `PhoneAttribute` - Validation Logic

So if you do want to provide validation, and you're using .NET 4.5+ or .NET Core, you can use the `[Phone]` attribute, but the mechanism for validation has changed over time as well and also you might have a different set of rules on what constitutes valid input for your business process.

.NET Framework initially used the following regular expression:

```cs
const string pattern = @"^(\+\s?)?((?<!\+.*)\(\+?\d+([\s\-\.]?\d+)?\)|\d+)([\s\-\.]?(\(\d+([\s\-\.]?\d+)?\)|\d+))*(\s?(x|ext\.?)\s?\d+)?$";
```

But this was deprecated in .NET Framework 4.7.2 per [this change description](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/Documentation/compatibility/aspnet-472-compat-doc.md), likely due to injection/security concerns layed out in the [Regular Expression Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices) from unconstrained input.

If you want to continue using regex validation, you'd have to set the following in the `configuration` > `appsettings` section of your `.config` file:

```xml
<add key="dataAnnotations:dataTypeAttribute:disableRegEx" value="false"/>
```

The Test project includes a sample of what inputs should pass/fail according to [PhoneAttributeTests.cs](https://source.dot.net/#System.ComponentModel.Annotations.Tests/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/PhoneAttributeTests.cs) and here's a [Regexr page](https://regexr.com/429je) if you want to test out matching input against the (deprecated) regular expression validation engine.

---

Here's some links for source code and documentation for different flavors of .NET:

```
                  | .NET Core         | .NET Core 2.1  |  .NET 4.7.2     | .NET           |
------------------|-------------------|----------------|-----------------|----------------|
DataTypeAttribute | github.com/dotnet | source.dot.net | referencesource | docs.microsoft |
PhoneAttribute    | github.com/dotnet | source.dot.net | referencesource | docs.microsoft |
```

**Note**: The current docs for `[Phone]` mistakenly remarks that the validation uses Regular Expressions, which has not been true since 4.7.2+ or anywhere in .NET core, so I've [submitted this PR to update](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/pull/686)